# With MS Graph API, how do I force my programmatically created Service Principals, MSIs, and IaC code to be scoped to my subscription only?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rbac, azure-service-principal

Active Directory Graph API is now fully deprecated, in favor of MS Graph API.

My company has given me my own Visual Studio Professional subscription. I also have a DevOps organization. I am the Owner role in both.

with AADG API, I could use Terraform, for example, to create Service Principals and manage roles. Service Connections in DevOps were scoped to my subscription.

Example:

```
## These are in my resource group
...
resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.example.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

...

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "kubweb_to_acr" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubweb.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
}
```

This used to work great. Now it does not. Now I get errors like:

```
Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '3520c717-e1cc-4d0b-b021-2f93a1b05d80' with object id '3520c717-e1cc-4d0b-b021-2f93a1b05d80' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write
```

and

```
ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData
│ error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
│ operation.
```

Even though I own my subscription, there is a parent organization above me. My SPs get scoped to their AD where I can't manage them. I can't use "Grant Admin Consent" through MS Graph API. Also, in DevOps, when I create an ARM Service Connection, for example, I scope it to my Subscription. It never scopes to my subscription, but the parent's, and I can't change its permissions.

How do I alter my development or scope my resources so that I don't have to defer to parent organization?

What role do they need to give me so I don't have to involve them?

I'm already the **owner** of my subscription. How do I create these types of resources in a way that I have full control over managing them again?

Side-note, it's interesting. I can use Azure CLI and run the same commands via terminal, and I have no problems creating or altering resources. The same commands `az ad sp create-for-rbac` don't throw any errors at all, and it's using the same permissions and scope defined in the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors you show are due to the service principal that Terraform is running as has not been authorized to perform the action in question. (From the Azure role assignment error, we can know this is the service principal with object ID "3520c717-e1cc-4d0b-b021-2f93a1b05d80".)

- To assign an Azure role to a user, group, or service principal (your first error), the service principal used by Terraform needs to be have been granted a role that includes the "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write" operation, scoped to (at least) scope you're trying to grant the role at (e.g. the specific Azure resource, the resource group it's in, or the subscription it's in). Typically, if you need to create Azure role assignments, this is the "Owner" role. More details from Terraform in [Allowing the Service Principal to manage the Subscription](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_certificate#allowing-the-service-principal-to-manage-the-subscription). If you're "Owner" of the Azure subscription, then you *will* be able to do this yourself.
- To create Azure AD application and service principals (your second error): The service principal used by Terraform needs to be granted permission to do this in the Azure AD tenant in question. For example, the app roles (application permissions) Application.Read.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy would suffice in many cases. These are actions that take place in the Azure AD tenant, so an Azure AD administrator will need to grant this access—you cannot do this on your own if you're not an admin of the Azure AD tenant. More details from Terraform in [Configuring a User or Service Principal for managing Azure Active Directory](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_configuration#azure-active-directory-permissions).

> How do I alter my development or scope my resources so that I don't have to defer to parent organization?

You could have an entirely separate Azure AD tenant (where you'd be administrator), and point the Azure subscription to trust that tenant. This may or may not be compatible with your organization's policies and practices.

> I'm already the owner of my subscription. How do I create these types of resources in a way that I have full control over managing them again?

Azure AD applications and service principals are not a part of your Azure subscription, they're in the "parent" Azure AD tenant. You (the user) probably *do* have permission over these objects (e.g. you're owner of them in Azure AD), but Terraform isn't running as you—it's running as a separate service principal.

> Side-note, it's interesting. I can use Azure CLI and run the same commands via terminal, and I have no problems creating or altering resources. The same commands az ad sp create-for-rbac don't throw any errors at all, and it's using the same permissions and scope defined in the pipelines.

You're probably connecting to Azure CLI as yourself (i.e. your user account), instead of the service principal Terraform is using. If you connect to Azure CLI using the same service principal (e.g. `az login --service-principal ...`), you'd likely experience the same errors, because that service principal hasn't been granted privileges over the Azure AD tenant and the Azure subscription yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for that fantastic explanation. In my pipeline logs, I see the following: `az login --service-principal -t c9678da8-892e-40dc-ae82-901eace67542 -u *** -p ***`  `az account set -s 0bfe77a8-517e-450b-a955-92f03bb4c40c`  Is this not the same thing as me running 'az login ; az account set -s <same login id>?

Comment: No, it's not the same. The command `az login --service-principal -t {tenant-id} -u {app-id} -p {client-secret}` is: connect as service principal `{app-id}`, using secret `{client-secret}`, in tenant `{tenant-id}`. Authorization will be evaluated against what the service principal has been granted access to do. The command `az login` is: sign in as a me (a user) in whatever tenant I belong in.  Authorization is for what you (the user) can do. The command `az account set -s {sub-id}` just selects which Azure subscription to act against.